# Build number list - Scheme

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

I need to build a list like:
`(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) (list 5 6))`, but there is an error in the following code:

```
(define example
  (lambda (a b)
    (let ((tmp (+ b 1)))
    (list '(1 b) '(2 tmp) '(3 3)))))

(example 1 4)
```

The result that I want is `(list (list 1 4) (list 3 5) (list 3 3))` but the result I get: `(list (list 1 'b) (list 2 'tmp) (list 3 3))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
(list (list 1 b) (list 2 tmp) '(3 3))
```

or

```
(list `(1 ,b) `(2 ,tmp) '(3 3))
```